# How to add button to "submit_row" context in django

Tags: django, view, admin

I would like to add an extra button to the submit row in django. 
Standard we get "delete", "save", "save and continue editing" and "save and add another". To this set I would like to add another button which would call a function on the model.

As far as I understand the template `change_form` is generated in one of the `admin.views`. The context `submit_row` is passed as context.

I want to edit the context of the admin view. Where can I find it in my filesystem?

Comment: When you say " Where can i find it in my filesytem?" you mean the change form admin template?

Comment: no i mean the view which renders the changeform.html with the submit_row as its context

Comment: Did you solve this?  If so, could you please post your solution.

Comment: no i didnt actually, i created a custom action on the table level. If you find anything, let me know!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From what I can tell, there are two relevant files.  The first is

```
.../django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_modify.py
```

which has the following section:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('admin/submit_line.html', takes_context=True)
def submit_row(context):
    """
    Displays the row of buttons for delete and save.
    """
    opts = context['opts']
    change = context['change']
    is_popup = context['is_popup']
    save_as = context['save_as']
    return {
        'onclick_attrib': (opts.get_ordered_objects() and change
                            and 'onclick="submitOrderForm();"' or ''),
        'show_delete_link': (not is_popup and context['has_delete_permission']
                              and (change or context['show_delete'])),
        'show_save_as_new': not is_popup and change and save_as,
        'show_save_and_add_another': context['has_add_permission'] and
                            not is_popup and (not save_as or context['add']),
        'show_save_and_continue': not is_popup and context['has_change_permission'],
        'is_popup': is_popup,
        'show_save': True
    }
```

And the second is

```
.../django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/submit_line.html
```

which is the following:

```
{% load i18n %}
<div class="submit-row">
{% if show_save %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save" {{ onclick_attrib }}/>{% endif %}
{% if show_delete_link %}<p class="deletelink-box"><a href="delete/" class="deletelink">{% trans "Delete" %}</a></p>{% endif %}
{% if show_save_as_new %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save as new' %}" name="_saveasnew" {{ onclick_attrib }}/>{%endif%}
{% if show_save_and_add_another %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother" {{ onclick_attrib }} />{% endif %}
{% if show_save_and_continue %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and continue editing' %}" name="_continue" {{ onclick_attrib }}/>{% endif %}
</div>
```

You can probably just add some custom html to the second file to display new buttons.

Answer (score 5):

Override the block tag [submit_buttons_bottom](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html#L67) in change_form.html